# Code has function specific variables changing values outside of scope

Tags: c++

This is FCFS cpu scheduling algorithm.

```
void findTurnAroundTime(int processes[], int n, int bt[], int wt[], int tat[])
{

// Calculating turnaround time by adding bt[i] + wt[i] 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        tat[i] = bt[i] + wt[i];
}

// Function to calculate average waiting and turn-around 
// times. 
void findavgTime(int processes[], int n, int bt[], int at[])
{
    int wt[n], tat[n];

// Function to find waiting time of all processes 
    findWaitingTime(processes, n, bt, wt, at);

// Function to find turn around time for all processes 
    findTurnAroundTime(processes, n, bt, wt, tat);

// Display processes along with all details 
    cout << "Processes " << " Burst Time " << " Arrival Time "
            << " Waiting Time " << " Turn-Around Time "
            << " Completion Time \n";
    int total_wt = 0, total_tat = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        total_wt = total_wt + wt[i];
        total_tat = total_tat + tat[i];
        int compl_time = tat[i] + at[i];
        cout << " " << i + 1 << "\t\t" << bt[i] << "\t\t" << at[i] << "\t\t"
                << wt[i] << "\t\t " << tat[i] << "\t\t " << compl_time << endl;
    }

    cout << "Average waiting time = " << (float) total_wt / (float) n;
    cout << "\nAverage turn around time = " << (float) total_tat / (float) n;
}
```

How are variables like wt and tat connected if they are decleared inside each function?(This is the main question)

full code is working.

Comment: Because `findavgTime` passes them to `findTurnAroundTime`?  I'm not sure what the confusion is here.

Comment: btw bad formatting and intendation makes it harder to read code and sometimes even prevent to graps basic things ;)

Comment: changes in findTurnAroundTime is reflecting in findavgTime. This is my confusion. They are decleared in there seperate functions

Comment: Are you being puzzled by [Array Decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)?

Comment: `findTurnAroundTime` accepts the pointer to the array `tat` as an argument, If you look at the implementation it populates this array with values.  So it is, in effect, space to store the results of the function.  In `findavgTime`, these results are stored in the local variable `tat` (not to be confused with the argument `tat` to `findTurnAroundTime`).  I can only presume that `findWaitingTime` does something similar to populate the `wt` local variable.

Comment: Parameters that look like arrays (`int tat[[`) are actually pointers (`int * tat` is equivalent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How are variables like `wt` and `tat` connected if they are decleared inside each function?

`wt` and `tat` are defined in `findavgTime`. (They are defined using a non-standard extension but that's a separate issue).

When `findavgTime` calls `findWaitingTime` and `findTurnAroundTime`, it passes those variables to the functions. The functions don't define them in their function body -- they are defined in the functions by way of function arguments. Since `wt` and `tat` are arrays, they decay to a pointer to the first elements of the respective arrays when `findWaitingTime` and `findTurnAroundTime` are called. Because of that, any changes made to the variables inside those functions are visible in `findavgTime` too.

You don't have to use the same variable names in the function arguments. You could use

```
void findTurnAroundTime(int processes[], int n, int bt[], int wt_here[], int tat_here[])
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        tat_here[i] = bt[i] + wt_here[i];
}
```

That won't change the behavior of the program.